# Kendo-UI : Datasource binding to form MVMM

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I am just a beginner in Kendo-UI. Looked for all documentation and i can't get the answer or example for my problem.
I am trying to bind mysql table to form by kendo.observable and kendo.data.DataSource.

My Html :

```
<body>
<div id="example">
<ul id="fieldlist">
<li><label for="fname">First Name:</label> <input id="fname" data-bind="value: patientname" class="k-textbox" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

My JS:

```
<script>
fenotypSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
   transport: {
    read: {url: function(){return "data_json/fenotyp_read.php?idpacjenta=1"}}  
    }
});
viewModel = kendo.observable({
  data: fenotypSource
});
kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
fenotypSource.read();
</script>
```

My JSON what i am getting from fenotyp_read:
{id: "1", idpatient: "1", patientname: "Smith"}

I am getting error : TypeError: e.slice is not a function
Than you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessary need Kendo UI DataSource for this. You can use single ObservableObject to bind specific object to form. Take a look at sample I made for you [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ajufi/6).

```
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  // you can use simple ajax request to get remote data
  // and bind result to observable viewModel
  /*
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "data_json/fenotyp_read.php?idpacjenta=1",
  }).done(function( data ) {
    var patient = new kendo.data.ObservableObject( data );
    viewModel.set("patient", patient);
  });
  */

  // this is local data to demonstrate ObservableObject
  var data = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    id: "1",
    idpatient: "1",
    patientname: "Smith"
  });

  var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    patient: data
  });

  kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel); 
});
```

```
  <form id="example">
    <label>Id:</label><span data-bind="text: patient.idpatient"> </span>
    <br/>
    <label>Patient Name:</label><input class="k-textbox" type="text" data-bind="value: patient.patientname"/>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks for youre answer everything is working great :)